# How to add projectile in a trebuchet?

Tags: rendering, animation

I made a trebuchet but have no clue of how to add the projectile and launch it.
guys pls help…
[image]

edit : problem solved!
[image]

Comment: Your current anim is Rigid Body?

Comment: Similar question here with an example how to fire a stone:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/239911/107598

Comment: @vklidu yes. the counterweight using rigid body as well as the long swinging thing. for the rope i use cloth sim.

Comment: @Blunder oh thanks for the link. i will give it a try

Comment: @Blunder when i attach the projectile with the rope (using 3 vetices) then the projectile sphere becomes weird https://ibb.co/N1pQkzf

Comment: wow dude, it works! https://ibb.co/0JH8BT2 thank you so much