# How do i simulate an object on a string, with the string being simulated, and can collide with something else?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I want to simulate the string being attached to one stationary point and attached to a bigger object, which can collide with other objects? I've tried so many different methods but I still can't find one that works.

Comment: maybe this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239911/trebuchet-rigid-body

Comment: Perhaps this would help - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226766/how-do-i-pin-a-ball-to-a-cloth-sim-rope-to-create-wrecking-ball/227382#227382