# How to create a physically based rope in blender?

Tags: animation, physics

How could one create a rope that can be controlled from both ends,
and which drops down when left alone
(using one object as a base to hang from and the other object as a weight on its end) ?

I'm trying to make a cable coming out of a character(base object) with an object on one of its ends (weight object) . I want the cable to work normally and swing around when the character moves but also would like to use one of its end to create an artificial mid swing pose for the cable when doing still renders.

Comment: maybe this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239911/trebuchet-rigid-body

Comment: You can use the Cloth modifier on the rope, use Pin groups to specify the end vertices and then parent those vertices to character bones (using Armature or Hooks). You will have to compute (bake) the animation each time you move it, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate a rope?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope)

Comment: @moonboots No, I actually wanted the two ends to droop down along with the object, like how it works in games. But thanks for your input!

Comment: @BuzzKirill yeah I had tried that but it only allows for one end to to be controlled. Though this method allows one end to dangle along with constrained objects, I was looking for a method for controlling both ends. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @pyCod3R I actually tried this method first, but with a cloth modifier. I redid it with the soft body phys but I still don't get the result I wanted. The pinned bodies give full control for sure but now they can't follow the physics of the rope as it gets affected by gravity. Thanks for your input !