# Shooting with Three Trebuchets

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, compile

What is the correct way to organize the animation of this scene? Three similar trebuchets (A, B and C) are available. The trebuchet file is attached in the question [*"Trebuchet Rigid Body"*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239911/trebuchet-rigid-body). The trebuchet is a set of objects from the **Rigid Body** and **Cloth** physics simulations. The trebuchets must move one by one in the direction of the arrows and start the shooting animation. The plan for the animation is as follows.

*Frame #1 - Frame #30*: Linear movement of *Trebuchet A* (one body forward). *Frame #32*: Start of *Trebuchet A* shooting animation.

*Frame #51 - Frame #80*: Linear movement of *Trebuchet B* (one body forward). *Frame #82*: Start of *Trebuchet B* shooting animation.

*Frame #101 - Frame #130*: Linear movement of *Trebuchet C* (one body forward). *Frame #132*: Start of *Trebuchet C* shooting animation.

I'm having trouble combining linear motion animation and physics simulations. Blender version 3.0 (Non-commercial, educational project).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the basic instructions how to combine rigid body animation and "manual" animation.

The important settings is "Animated":

[image]

> Note: You cannot have both: Manual/animated animation AND rigid body
> physics, but you can change it each frame.

So here is a very simple setup:

i have a cube animated with two location keyframes:

On first and second keyframe, the cube will be lifted up in the air.

[image]

on the second keyframe, animated (on) is keyframed:

[image]

on the third keyframe, animated (off) is keyframed, so that gravity starts working and the cube falls by itself (gravity).

result:

[image]

> Note: Blender is "clever". It keeps the speed the animated object has
> and "combines" this with rigid body physics. So the cube doesn't
> straight fall down but "flies" a bit further because of its initial
> speed.